# Async Task .Net 4.5

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a requirement for a function A to start a longer running asynchronous method function B (includes web service calls).

function A should return even if function B has not yet returned.

function B does not return any data and should execute even when it's calling function A has returned

Using .Net 4.5 C#, what would the best code be, and can you forsee any threading issues?

There's a lot of examples out there on the .net but it's not so simple to find the code for purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> function A should return even if function B has not yet returned.

In this case, the key is that you should not `await` the call for `B`.

> start a longer running asynchronous method function B (includes web service calls).

In general, if the bulk of the operations are web service calls, you should *not* use `Task.Run`.  Task.Run will execute the work on a background thread, which is likely not necessary as you can use asynchronous IO.

Instead, create your method an `async Task B()`, use the normal `await` mechanism within the method, and call it.  By default, this will cause a compiler warning, but you can work around that by creating a `FireAndForget` extension method which logs exceptions that occur.

This can be as simple as:

```
public static async void FireAndForget(this Task task)
{
    try
    {
        await task;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Log the exception
    }
}
```

This also provides the benefit of logging issues that occur within `B()`.

Comment: The benefit of being able to log is a great bonus!

Comment: Reed, Im using your extension method but it's just hanging on the await Task. Am I using it as intended? var t = new Task( () => DoStuff() t.FireAndForget();

Comment: @STeveWard In general, use `Task.Run` instead of `new Task` - you won't need to call start then

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use `Task.Run`, which executes an action on a new thread:

```
public void A()
{
    // Do something...

    Task.Run(B);
    // or, if you need to pass arguments to B:
    // Task.Run(() => B(x, y, z));

    // Do something else...
}

public void B()
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Be careful not to let any exception be thrown from B, or it will crash the process.

Comment: Very simple then! And this should work even if A returns before B has finished?

Comment: @SteveWard, yes; `Task.Run` returns immediately, while B continues to run on a separate thread.

Comment: I'd argue that this is not necessarily a great practice, especially since the OP pointed out that they are using web service calls (async IO)....

Comment: @ReedCopsey, well, it depends on how B is implemented; if it uses async calls, there's no benefit in running it on a new thread, but if it only makes synchronous calls, offloading the work to a new thread will prevent freezing the UI.

Comment: And actually, and async call to a web service doesn't guarantee that it won't block, because some operations are done synchronously in .NET's HTTP stack (e.g. DNS resolution)